# 'Finally' equivalent for If/Elif statements in Python

Tags: python, finally

Does Python have a `finally` equivalent for its `if/else` statements, similar to its `try/except/finally` statements? Something that would allow us to simplify this:

```
 if condition1:
      do stuff
      clean up
 elif condition2:
      do stuff
      clean up
 elif condition3:
      do stuff
      clean up
 ...
 ...
```

to this:

```
 if condition1:
      do stuff
 elif condition2:
      do stuff
 elif condition3:
      do stuff
 ...
 ...
 finally:
      clean up
```

Where `finally` would only be called only after a condition was met and its 'do stuff' run? Conversely, if no condition was met, the `finally` code would not be run.

I hate to spout blasphemy, but the best way I can describe it is there being a `GOTO` statement at the end of each block of 'do stuff' that led to `finally`.

Essentially, it works as the opposite of an `else` statement. While `else` is only run if no other conditions are met, this would be ran ONLY IF another condition was met.

Comment: Not really. It sounds like you might be able to simplify your logic.

Comment: No... there is no `finally` for `if/else`

Comment: Addendum: the if may contain some return statements in need of cleanup after them.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

It can be done totally non-hackily like this:

```
def function(x,y,z):
    if condition1:
        blah
    elif condition2:
        blah2
    else:
        return False

    #finally!
    clean up stuff.
```

In some ways, not as convenient, as you have to use a separate function.  However, good practice to not make too long functions anyway.  Separating your logic into small easily readable (usually maximum 1 page long) functions makes testing, documenting, and understanding the flow of execution a lot easier.

One thing to be aware of is that the `finally` clause will not get run in event of an exception.  To do that as well, you need to add `try:` stuff in there as well.

Comment: The `finally` clause won't run either if `else: return False` is met.

Comment: This construct doesn't work if the if/else/finally is used to break from an outer loop.

Comment: @RolfBly that's the purpose of the code: if you want to run the "finally" block only if one of the conditions is met, you cannot include the "else" block in the condition, otherwise the finally block will always run.

Comment: @Vincenzoo Yup, I know. Perhaps I should have suggested to incorporate this in the explanation.

Answer (score 16):

you can use try

```
try:
    if-elif-else stuff
finally:
    cleanup stuff
```

the exception is raised but the cleanup is done

Answer (score 10):

Your logic is akin to this:

```
cleanup = True
if condition1:
    do stuff
elif condition2:
    do stuff
elif condition3:
    do stuff
....
else:
    cleanup = False

if cleanup:
    do the cleanup
```

Ugly, but it is what you asked

Comment: See, I had exactly this in my own code, and I agree, it is VERY ugly. I was surprised when I went looking that there really is no good way to beautify this.

Comment: It is, but maybe you should rethink your program's logic, because `if/elif/else` is just not supposed to follow that kind of construct

Answer (score 8):

A little late to the party, but see the question has been active recently.

Usually I would make a context manager like this

```
class CleanUp(object):

    class Cancel(Exception):
        pass

    def __init__(self, f_cleanup):
        self.f_cleanup = f_cleanup

    def __enter__(self):
        return self

    def __exit__(self, exception_type, exception_value, traceback):

        cancelled = exception_type and issubclass(exception_type, self.__class__.Cancel)

        if not cancelled:
            self.f_cleanup()

        return not exception_type or cancelled

    def cancel(self):
        raise self.__class__.Cancel
```

And then you can use it like this

```
def cleanup():
    print "Doing housekeeping"


with CleanUp(cleanup) as manager:
    if condition1:
        do stuff
    elif condition2:
        do stuff
    else:
        manager.cancel()
```

Comment: Oh I like this one.  Very DRY.

Comment: @DylanYoung Ye, I usually keep this around as I find that this task is more common than one would think. Just keep in mind that this example does the clean up unless cancel is called, meaning also on any kind of exception.

Answer (score 5):

The answer of mhlester has repetitive code, an improved version might be as follows:

```
class NoCleanUp(Exception):
    pass

try:
    if condition1:
        do stuff
    elif condition2:
        do stuff
    else:
        raise NoCleanUp
except NoCleanUp:
    pass
else:
    cleanup
```

Answer (score 1):

Another suggestion, which might suit you if the conditions are pre-computed.

```
if condition1:
    do stuff
elif condition2:
    do stuff
...
if any([condition1, condition2, ...]):
    clean_up
```

This would be a pain if you were evaluating the conditions as part of your if statements, because in that case you would have to evaluate them a second time for the `any` function...unless Python is smarter than I realise.

Answer (score 0):

Is this hideous?

```
for _ in range(1):
    if condition1:
        do stuff
        break
    elif condition2:
        do stuff
        break
else:
    finally stuff
```

How about this?

```
class NoFinally(Exception):
    pass

try:
    if condition1:
        do stuff
        raise NoFinally
    elif condition2:
        do stuff
        raise NoFinally
except NoFinally:
    pass
else:
    finally
```

Honestly, I hate both of these

Comment: Yeah, they're both pretty functional, but also pretty ugly. I feel like there's got to be a better way!

Comment: Both of these still have the problem of repeated cleanup code; in this case break or raise.

Comment: These both do the opposite of the desired behavior (which is to run the "finally" code if any of the if branches were met).

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
from .actions import stuff1, stuff2

actions={condition1: stuff1, condition2: stuff2}
for condition in actions:
    if condition:
        actions[condition]()
        cleanup()
        break
```

Caveats are of course that your condition keys have to be unique and hashable. You can get around this by using a different data structure.

Comment: Also, this is a good pythonic model for switch statements methinks

Answer (score -2):

I gotchu:

```
def finally(self):
    pass

if 2 > 1:
    print('over')
elif 2 < 1:
    print('under')
self.finally()
print('done')
```

Comment: I think you've missed the point which is that finally() should only run if one of the conditions is true, whereas for your code finally() always runs