# How to make sure a piece of code runs before a method exits

Tags: java, closures

I have a method with if-else cases, and more than one return statement, depending on the exact flow.

I have one line of code that needs to happen just before the return statement (e.g. releaseResources).

I want to be sure that this line is executed no matter what.

Is there a nice way of doing that in java?
Something that will make sure a piece of code is executed before leaving a closure?

Comment: Use try {} finally{}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a try-finally block. Here is an example:

```
public Something someMethod() {
    try {
        if(someStatement) {
            return new Something();
        } else {
            return new SomethingElse();
        }
    } finally {
        // this is always executed, even if there is an Exception
    }
}
```

The question is if this is really what you want. It sounds like your code might actually be better (more readable) if it has two methods. Like this:

```
public Something createSomething() {
    if(someStatement) {
         return new Something();
    } else {
        return new SomethingElse();
    }
}

public Something someMethod() {
    Something something = createSomething();
    // Do the thing that always needs to be done
    return something;
}
```

This separates the things you are doing into two methods. Now if the problem is that the first method can throw an exception and you want to do something nonetheless, you can still use a finally. But it might be better to capture and handle the Exception.

Also: You've noted that you want to close a resource. In that case I would suggest you look into try-with-resources:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

An example here:

```
private String someMethod() throws IOException {
    // Java automatically closes the following Readers:
    try (BufferedReader br =
               new BufferedReader(new FileReader("/path"))) {
        return br.readLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending of the programming language you're using, the try-catch-finally exist:

[Example from other post about launch code after the if-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21612910/finally-equivalent-for-if-elif-statements-in-python)

Finally statement will launch when try-catch condition ends

SORRY FOR EDIT

Comment: _finally is useful for more than just exception handling — it allows the programmer to avoid having cleanup code accidentally bypassed by a return, continue, or break._ [source](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `try/finally` block, if that's what you really want.

```
try {
    if (...) return ...;
    else if (...) return ...;
    else return ...;
} finally {
    doSomething();
}
```

The code in the `finally` block will always be executed when you leave the `try` block, in particular at any `return` statement.

Answer (score 0):

The `finally` block will always be executed even if an Exception is thrown.

```
try {
     ...
     if () {
         return;
     else {
         return;
     }
} finally {
    // Release resources
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the main programming good practices is that each method should have one and only one return statement. If you have many possible values, you tend to keep the value in an object and return it at the end.

E.g:

```
public int func(boolean condition) {
    if(condition) {
        return 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

should be made like this

```
public int func(boolean condition) {
    int num; 

    if(condition) {
        num = 1;
    } else {
        num = 0;
    }

    return num;
}
```

As you can probably see, it's quite simple to ensure you call your method before return this way, adding it right before the only return.